# LinearLayout not working when creating text view2

Tags: java, android

I'm facing a problem where the code works fine but my text (textview) doesn't appear in the linearlayout which I'm not sure why

this is my code:

```
LinearLayout linearScrollableMin = findViewById(R.id.linearScrollableMin);
  TextView tryingTV1 = new TextView(this);
  tryingTV1.setBackgroundColor(000);
  tryingTV1.setText("1");
  tryingTV1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

  ((LinearLayout) linearScrollableMin).addView(tryingTV1);
```

and a picture of the component tree: [image]

Answer (score 0):

**There are some things I want to note here:**

1. Always set the background color using java binary numbers (here `0x000000`) --> `int`. Setting the color black would work with 000, because black has the ID 0, but it wouldn't work for any other colors.
2. When you add a `TextView` to a `ViewGroup` (and `LinearLayout extends ViewGroup`), its `LayoutParams` are automatically overridden. The `LayoutParams` are always given to a view by its parent and describe all properties of a view in relation to the parent / siblings
3. You are casting a `LinearLayout` to `LinearLayout` ;)

**Actual solution:**

Most probably, your `LinearLayout` is not displayed itself, so its childs can't be either. You can check whether this is true by either calling `linearScrollableMin.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)` or just add `android:background="@color/blue"` to your resource file (and remove it later).

If this is the case, work yourself up in the parent tree and see if a sibling blocks out a view in a parent (by f.e. having the width and height `MATCH_PARENT`). In this case, just use `RelativeLayout` and you'll be fine.

**Another possible reason**

could be, that the `textColor` of `tryingTV1` is `Color.BLACK` (which it is in this case) and your background is also `Color.BLACK` (which the background of your `TextView` is). You can solve this by calling `tryingTV1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);`.

**Edit (how to copy a TextView)**

If you want to clone a `TextView` that you created in your layout file (**NOT** by calling `new TextView(this);`), you copy it by calling:

```
TextView realTextView = findViewById(R.id.whateverView);
ViewGroup layout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.whateverLayout);
tryingTV1 = layout.getChildAt(0); // I assume that the TextView is your first child in the layout, if it is somewhere inside of a nested layout, you have to call `getChildAt(index)` multiple times and always cast to `ViewGroup`, or simply just use my suggestion below.
```

There is **no way** of cloning a TextView that you created by calling `new TextView(this);`, but you might try to create one by copying all the nessesary attributes:

```
TextView realTextView = new TextView(this);
// do something with the realTextView

copy = new TextView(this);
copy.setText(realTextView.getText());
copy.setTextColor(realTextView.getTextColor());
copy.setBackground(realTextView.getBackground());
...
tryingTV1 = copy;
```

Comment: Just  a quick question if I want to copy a Text View to tryingTV1 do you know how to do it?

Comment: Hi @omerbt, I edited the post! If the answer is helpful, please accept it ;)